# How do I use pattern matching for elements within a list?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, matching

I'm working on Advent of Code's coding challenges and I'm on day one. I've read from a file that contains nothing but ((()(())(( so I'm looking to turn each '(' to 1 and each ')' to a -1 so I can compute them. But I'm having issues when I **map** findFloor over **source**. I'm getting a type mismatch. Everything looks right to me and that's the weird part because it's not working.

```
import scala.io._

object Advent1 extends App {

// Read from file
val source = Source.fromFile("floor1-Input.txt").toList

// Replace each '(' with 1 and each ')' with -1, return List[Int]
def findFloor(input: List[Char]):Int = input match {

        case _ if input.contains('(') => 1
        case _ if input.contains(')') => -1 

}

val floor = source.map(findFloor)   

}
```

**Error output**

> error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : List[Char] => Int
>
> required: Char => ?
>
> val floor = source.map(findFloor)
>                                  ^    one error found

What I'm I doing wrong here ? / what I'm I missing  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala `map` works [over an elements](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/trait-traversable.html) rather than whole collection. Try this:

```scala
val floor = source.map {
    case '(' => 1
    case ')' => -1
}.sum
```

Comment: You can safely drop `(_ match`, `.map { case ... }` works too, it defines partial anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm trying to get the source.map(findFloor) approach to work. As far as I can tell I'm giving the function a List of Chars and it expects to receive a List of Chars. So I don't understand what the issue is. Plus I go it to work before, unfortunately I closed the terminal where I was running the Scala repl where it did work.

Comment: @Native all you need to do is to make a sum of mapped list. I've updated my answer

Comment: @vsminkov. That works! Yet I'm still left unsatisfied as to why the findFloor function is not mapping over source properly in the first place. You could say I'm left with mixed feelings. On the one hand, I have a solution and on the other I'm left with an unresolved problem.

Comment: @Native actually your `findFloor` function is incorrect. To able to pass it to `map` method you should implement it using `findFloor(input: Char): Int` signature (compiler complains about this issue). After that  `source.map(findFloor)` will produce list of integers which you'll be able to sum

Comment: Awesome. Now I got it!!! Funny I thought I was getting a List of Char by doing val source = Source.fromFile("floor1-Input.txt").toList and that's why I used a signature of input:List[Char]:Int in the findFloor functon. I didn't think I could just receive the values from val source as just Char, because I figured I had to include the List container as well. In any event, I appreciate the help! Thanks.

Comment: @vsminkov This was the missing piece I was not understanding: When you said: "Scala map works over an elements rather than whole collection."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute them in an sequential way, you could even do the computations directly by using foldLeft.

```
val computation = source.foldLeft(0)( (a, b) => {
  b match {
      case '(' => a + 1
      case ')' => a - 1
  }
})
```

It's simply adding up all values and returning the acummulated value. For ( it's adding and for ')' it's substracting.

The first argument is the starting value, a is the value from the previous step and b is the actual element therefore the char.

Answer (score 0):

You're error is probably caused because the pattern match is not defined for all chars. You missing a match for all others, case _ => 0 for example.
An other option would be to use 'collect' since this accepts a PartialFunction and ignores all not matching elements.

The suggested 'fold' solution is the better approach here I think.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out as well. Also, I only needed 2 cases because the file I was reading in is nothing but the characters '(' and ')'. Obviously, if things were different then, I'd need more cases to deal with.

Comment: But the compiler does not know there are 2 different chars in the file. Looking at it again I see you're matching the List instead of the items in the List. To match elements either use 'map' using a function or 'collect' using partial function.